# Dronekit python

Tags: python

Всем привет.
Могу ли я подключиться к любым дронам используя dronekit?
Или dronekit поддерживает только определённые типы дронав?
Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Что по этому поводу говорит документация?

Comment: Ничего. Может я что-то упустил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитай про [MAVlink](https://mavlink.io/en/) (протокол для обмена сообщения с дронами и взаимодействия между компонентами дрона).

Comment: Хорошо бы подробностей в ответ добавить.